# Has anyone experienced issues with Twilio's call service recently?

Tags: twilio

I'm monitoring a Customer Relationship Management which uses Twilio's service and recently we experienced a lot of issues with call function, so I just want to know if the same case happens to any other client of Twilio.

I would like to hear feedback from other clients of Twilio.